# Javascript showing div box doesn't work

Tags: javascript, random

I'm sorry, I'm very new to JS but I need it for work...

Can you just quickley tell me what is wrong with this script? I just want the div box to be visible every second time when someone loads the page...

```js
<body onload="script();">

<script type="text/javascript">
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1  ;
 
 if (random<1) {
 document.getElementById('ele').style.display = 'block';
};
</script>



<div style="display: none;" id="ele">Div-Box<br />
 </div>
</body>
```

Cheers,
Till

Comment: Where is your function? (`script();`)

Comment: if you want it to show it on every **second page view** then random number will not do that obviously, since it is *random*... wouldn't you agree?

Comment: also your code can never work since it is written **above** the `div` so, from the perspective  of the script, the `div` doesn't exist. scripts should be written at the end of the `body` tag

Answer (score 1):

Using random won't guarantee that the div will be shown every second time the page is loaded. To do that you need to keep track of how many times a user has opened the page. You can do this in `localStorage`.

```
<body>
  <script>
    var viewCount = localStorage.getItem('viewCount') || 1; // default to 1 the first time
    if (viewCount % 2 === 0) { // if it's an even number
      document.getElementById('ele').setAttribute('style', 'display: block');
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from your logic  you are calling script() function on `onload` but it is not defined.

```html
<body onload="script();">

<script type="text/javascript">
function script(){
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1  ;
 console.log(random);
 if (random>1) {
 document.getElementById('ele').style.display = 'block';
};
}
</script>



<div style="display: none;" id="ele">Div-Box<br />
 </div>
</body>
```